# Just upgraded to Django 1.4 and getting error with messages

Tags: django

I just upgraded to Django 1.4 and it has broken a couple things including messaging.

Here's the error I get when trying to change a avatar:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'message_set'
Exception Location: /Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in inner, line 185
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/spicestore/apps/avatar/views.py" in change
  76.             request.user.message_set.create(
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  185.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /avatar/change/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'message_set'
```

Also, messaging no longer works on the site. What are the changes in Django 1.4 that could be causing this and has anyone overcome a similar issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django introduced a messages app in 1.2 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#messages-framework)), and deprecated the old user messages API.

In Django 1.4, the old message_set API has been removed completely, so you'll have to update your code. If you follow the [messages docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/), you should find it pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

And then

```
def foo(request):
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Your message.")
```

Answer (score 0):

What is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`?

Do you have `'django.contrib.messages',` included there?

Something like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From Django 1.4 docs
To enable message functionality, in settings.py do the following:

Edit the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting and make sure it contains

```
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'
```

If you are using a storage backend that relies on sessions (the default), `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` must be enabled and appear before `MessageMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Edit the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting and make sure it contains

```
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
```

Add `'django.contrib.messages'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting

As far as django-avatar is concerned.  Use the master files found here: https://github.com/chadpaulson/django-avatar/tree/master/avatar