# Django Messages Attribute Error

Tags: python, django

I'm using [arneb/django messages](http://files.arnebrodowski.de/software/django-messages/Documentation/) for handling messages on my django site. Whenever I send a message to a user, it will bring out the  below error and the message will still deliver silently.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 20, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_messages/views.py", line 77, in compose
request.user.message_set.create(

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 185, in inner
return func(self._wrapped, *args)

    AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'message_set'
```

I've been trying to fixed this but yet no success. How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look through the docs ("You need at least django 1.0") suggest that this is a pretty old package. The messages framework was removed quite some time ago.

I'd suggest looking around for something else to use

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I'm using django 1.4 . I just checked this out: github.com/arneb/django-messages don't know if it will support django 1.4 . What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

This error is fixed in the GitHub repository. Only the old release on PyPi is incompatible with Django 1.4.

https://github.com/arneb/django-messages

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have upgraded to Django 1.4, which is not compatible with the version of django messages that you are using. See this post for an explanation: [Just upgraded to Django 1.4 and getting error with messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283253/just-upgraded-to-django-1-4-and-getting-error-with-messages/13284882#13284882)

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I'm using django 1.4 . I just checked this out: https://github.com/arneb/django-messages  don't know if it will support django 1.4 . What do you think?

Comment: The readme on github says: 'The current trunk/head is compatible with Django 1.2', so it might work.